# Possible to test a game on multiple machines without owning multiple machines?

Tags: opengl, c++, testing

I'm working on a small PC game (Uses custom engine written in C++) that I would like to test. Not as much the gameplay but the engine itself. See if there are any crashes, errors, glitches or missing library files. I'm using OpenGL for graphics and that always does unexpected things with a different driver / GPU.

At the same time I don't yet want to give out the half-finished game for public testing. Is there such online service that allows you to upload a program to run and gives you back the result of the run. A log file or a screencap or what not. Or is it possible to do such testing with VirtualBox?

Comment: You can always rely on a closed beta. It's a nice middleground between hiring testers and releasing a broken game. Or you can ask some of your friends to help test it out.

Comment: If you correctly separated your engine, you can also distibute a simple test program instead of the game.